# bash sort by numeric substring

Tags: bash, sorting

In bash shell I'm trying to sort by a numeric value at the end of each line (sort by number of packets)
Tried to use "`sort -k6 -t '=' -n` but not working.

Input:

```
type udp ip src=192.168.2.173 dport=53 packets=1
type udp ip src=192.168.2.168 dport=53 packets=1
type udp ip src=192.168.2.173 dport=53 packets=1
type udp ip src=192.168.2.170 dport=53 packets=560
type udp ip src=192.168.2.173 dport=53 packets=1
type udp ip src=192.168.2.175 dport=53 packets=1
type udp ip src=192.168.2.173 dport=53 packets=11
type udp ip src=192.168.2.178 dport=53 packets=1
type udp ip src=192.168.2.162 dport=53 packets=23
type udp ip src=192.168.2.173 dport=53 packets=75
type udp ip src=192.168.2.173 dport=53 packets=7
type udp ip src=192.168.2.173 dport=53 packets=100
type udp ip src=192.168.2.173 dport=53 packets=1
type udp ip src=192.168.2.173 dport=53 packets=200
type udp ip src=192.168.2.162 dport=7777 packets=75
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You chose `=` as the field separator. In each line there are exactly three separators, so the "numeric value at the end of each line" is the field number 4.

These are the fields:

```
type udp ip src=192.168.2.162 dport=7777 packets=75
111111111111111 2222222222222222222 333333333333 44
```

Therefore:

```
sort -k4 -t '=' -n
```

Alternatively you can choose space as the separator and then the field will be indeed 6, but you need to tell `sort` to start at the 9th character of the field.

```
type udp ip src=192.168.2.162 dport=7777 packets=75
1111 222 33 44444444444444444 5555555555 6666666666
                                         123456789…
```

So this will also work:

```
sort -k6.9 -t ' ' -n
```